# How to select the direct parent of an element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time selecting the direct parent div of an input element in jquery, here's what I've tried so far, I've also included the output I got from each one when I tried to press enter on the text box with the placeholder of bunso:

```
<script src="jq.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#grand_lolo').keypress(function(e){
        var box = $(this).parents('div').attr('id'); //undefined
        var box2 = $(this).parent().closest('div').attr('id'); //undefined
        var box3 = $(this).parent().attr('id'); //(an empty string)
        var box4 = $(this).find("div:first").attr("id"); //lolo
        var box5 = $(this).find("div").attr("id"); //lolo
        var box6 = $(this).find("div:last").attr("id"); //apo
        var box7 = $(this).closest('div').attr('id'); //grand_lolo
        console.log(box);
        console.log(box2);
        console.log(box3);
        console.log(box4);
        console.log(box5);
        console.log(box6);

        console.log(box7);
    });


});
</script>
<div id="grand_lolo">
    <input type="text" placeholder="grand_lolo"/>
    <div id="lolo">
        <input type="text" placeholder="lolo"/>
        <div id="mama">
            <input type="text" placeholder="mama"/>
            <div id="ate">
                <input type="text" placeholder="ate"/>
            </div><!--end of ate-->

            <div id="bunso">
                <input type="text" placeholder="bunso"/>
            </div><!--end of bunso-->
        </div><!--end of mama-->

        <div id="papa">
            <input type="text" placeholder="papa"/>
            <div id="kuya">
                <input type="text" placeholder="kuya"/>

                <div id="apo">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="apo"/>
                </div><!--end of apo-->
            </div><!--end of kuya-->
        </div><!--end of papa-->
    </div><!--end of lolo-->
</div><!--end of grand_lolo-->
```

As you can see the correct output should be the id of the div directly enclosing the input element.

Comment: I thing it would be more correct to bind keypress events to INPUT field instead of parent container.

Comment: You are binding the keypress to the top level div `grand_lolo`, so `this` in your handler function is not going to be an input box.  if you want the textbox that generated the keypress try `e.target`

Comment: To build on the preceding comments, it you want to add the handler to `input` descendants of `#grand_lolo`, use either `$('#grand_lolo input').keypress(...` or $('#grand_lolo').delegate('input', 'keypress', ...`. If you're using the latest jQuery, then use `.on()` instead of `.delegate` (see http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ http://api.jquery.com/on/). You only need to use on/delegate if the input elements will be added after the handler has been bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just attach your `keypress` to `input` elements - http://jsfiddle.net/hyEhh/

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: my question is, would the event still execute if the input element is set to readonly?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input").each(function(){
   var id=$(this).parent().attr("id");
    $(this).attr("placeHolder",id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you are doing in wrong way. in this way you are selecting parent div by using it id.
try something like

```
$('input[placeholder="grand_lolo"]')keypress(function(e){
   var box = $(this).parent().attr('id'); 
   console.log(box);

});
```

If you want to do this for all the input then remove `[placeholder="grand_lolo"]` from selector.